# Passing instances to function within the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, keyword-argument

Suppose I have something like:

```
class MyClass_1(object):
    def __init__(self, name, x1, x2, x3):
        self.name = name
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.x3 = x3

    def run(self):
        if self.name == 'func1':
            result = self.func1()
        elif self.name == 'func2':
            result = self.func2() 
        return result

    def func1(self):
        return Myclass_2(x1=self.x1, x2=self.x2, x3=self.x3).func() 

    def func2(self):
        return Myclass_3(x1=self.x1, x2=self.x2, x3=self.x3).func() 


class MyClass_2(object):
    def __init__self, **kwargs): 
        self.__dict__.update((k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items())

    def func(self):
        return #do something to the interested instances 

class MyClass_3(object):
    def __init__self, **kwargs): 
        self.__dict__.update((k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items())

    def func(self):
        return #do something to the interested instances
```

**How do I skip having to explicitly initialize `MyClass_2` or `MyClass_3`?**

That is, instead of having to write
`Myclass_2(x1 = self.x1, x2 = self.x2, x3 = self.x3).func()`
is there a way to pass in all the instances that I have initialized for `MyClass_1` to save the redundancy?

Comment: `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)` works just fine too...

Comment: @AjaySinghRana. That makes little or no sense in this context

Comment: @TomKarzes I just forgot to add it in  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass a group of something, put it in a container. If those things need to be named, put them in a mapping:

```
def __init__(self, name, x1, x2, x3):
    self.name = name
    self.x = {
        'x1': x1,
        'x2': x2,
        'x3': x3,
    }
```

Now you can use that mapping cleanly every time:

```
def func1(self):
    return Myclass_2(**self.x).func()
```

Another thing you might want to consider is to remove the redundancy in `run`:

```
def run(self):
    return getattr(self, self.name)()
```

You can actually take it a step further and map function names to objects that have a `func`. For this, you'll want to define `MyClass_1` *after* `MyClass_2` and `MyClass_3`:

```
class MyClass_1(object):
    delegates = {
        'func1': MyClass_2,
        'func2': MyClass_3
    }

    def __init__(self, name, x1, x2, x3):
        self.name = name
        self.x = {
            'x1': x1,
            'x2': x2,
            'x3': x3,
        }

    def run(self):
        return self.delegates[self.name](**self.x).func()
```

Comment: Nice! This is exactly what I am looking for actually :)

Comment: @KAJ226. See the update. It makes things even more succinct. I assumed you're OK with getting rid of the redundant wrapper functions.

Comment: Okay, now I want to give you multiple up votes!! :) Thank you!